# How to redirect all subdomain urls to main domain

Tags: regex, linux, apache, .htaccess, redirect

For some reason search engines are indexing my addon domains on my hosting. They should not do that.

For example I just found urls like

> addondomain/maindomain.com

how to prevent this happening? How did search engines even find my addondomains?

What is the solution here? I tried this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^addondomain\.maindomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.maindomain\.com [L]
```

but when I visit the url for example

`addondomain/maindomain.com`  for example nothing happens?

Comment: RewriteRule ^ http://www\.maindomain\.com  [L,R]. Put it like this.

Comment: addondomain/maindomain.com? Did you mean addondomain.maindomain.com?

Comment: yes exactly, made a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Try to Change in .httaccess file. You can replace your rule with this rule::

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =shop.domain.abc
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.abc/? [R=301,L]
```

Using %{REQUEST_URI} will cause original URI to be copied in target. Trailing ? in target will strip off any pre-existing query string.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a further explanation to my comment on your question.

> how to prevent this happening? How did search engines even find my
>   addondomains?

Google can easily find these subdomains on your site. To prevent this from happening, you can set a redirection with a 301 status code to inform Google that it should not index the addon domain. By doing this, Google will update its index as well.

This is a very common scenario with shared hosting and specially when you use CPanel. In Hostgator's support pages, you can see they have mentioned about this behavior.

> **Addon URL Example**
>
> For the primary domain abc.com, if you assign the addon domain 123.com
>   to the folder "123," the following URLs would be correct:
>
> ```
> abc.com/123
> 123.abc.com
> 123.com
> ```
>
> All three of these paths would access the same directory and show the
>   same website. For visitors going to 123.com, there is no evidence that
>   they are being routed through 123.abc.com.

https://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/what-is-an-addon-domain

You can fix this by adding the following to your `.httaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^addondomain\.maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.maindomain.com [R=301,L]
```

> NC - match in a case-insensitive manner.
>
> R - causes a HTTP redirect to be issued to the browser. When given as
>   `R=301` it will be issued with a 301 status code which is required to
>   inform Google that their index should be updated accordingly.
>
> L - Causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most
>   contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will
>   be processed.

===========================================================

Edit: Updated to add redirection to all domains, as requested in the comments.

To do this, you can simply check if the hostname is equal to your main domain, and if it's not, redirect it to the main domain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.maindomain.com [R=301,L]
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Can you please write code for all the addon domains? I have 5 addondomains on that account.....thank!

Comment: thank you for update....but are you sure it will work... i used your previous three liner code that you gave me but if I visit the url of     addon.maindomain.com  it does not redirect to maindomain.com     i put the code in htaccess.....but it does not work

Comment: put the code in `.htaccess` (dot is required) also put it in your `public_html` directory of your main domain.